How to get online status of my users on my NextJs App
My NextAuth Option Code is (only the important part)
 callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.email = user.email;
        token.role = user.role;
        token.nickname = user.nickname;
      }
       
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = token.id as string;
        session.user.email = token.email as string;
        session.user.role = token.role as string;
        session.user.nickname = token.nickname as string;
      }
      return session;
    }
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 600,
  },
  jwt: {
    maxAge: 600
  }
}

As I'm not storing sessions, I am confused on how to get real-time update on if the user is online. I know websockets will be used but NextJs is not pretty good with Socket.io. Is there any workaround to do this. I want last active and online status of users on my app.
I tried setting up websocket application on express but so many CORS Errors were getting to me, and I knew if I'm going to deploy my app on vercel, it's not gonna work anyways. So I'm thinking of any other way to achieve this functionality.

If it's really that hard to store these information with jwt, why didn't you simply use database strategy instead?

Because using database strategy was'nt necessary as I don't have the requirement to store sessions in a database.
